# How do cross chain transactions work?

Tags: cross-chain

I noticed that

1. USDT is on ETH, TRON, Solana, Algorand etc
2. USDC is on ETH, Solana, Algorand etc
3. BUSD is on ETH and BSC

Could somebody explain how this works to me? I understand how a Bitcoin like blockchain works but am not sure how cross chain transactions work.

Are the public addresses different for each chain? Can a ETH address send to a SOL address or a TRX address?

Answer (score 2):

They are like same merchandise in different stores.
Tether mint USDT on different chains and Circle do the same for USDC.

You can not send your chain A asset directly to chain B from a wallet.

Some chains provide bridges to let you bridge assets from one to another though.

Comment: Gotcha, so chain bridging is not possible without a third party.

Comment: Its more about needing infrastructure than 3rd party in place.